# How to send UDP packet using javascript to local network broadcast

Tags: javascript, udp, broadcast

I have build an android application that listen to the UDP broadcast url (eg: 192.168.1.255), and a website that should send a UDP packet to the broadcast url to find all devices connected to the same network at the moment, that will respond to the broadcast message by sending another broadcast to the same url.
is there anyway to send UDP packet using native javascript? if not is there any alternative?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've edited the question, I mean network broadcast eg: 192.168.1.255

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/dgram.html

Comment: So the only solution is to use nodejs?

Comment: No, you could use any other JS runtime, but you definitely can't send arbitrary UDP packets from a browser context.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After so many research and asking, looks like there is no way to send UDP packet from native javascript due to security concerns